# Is stomach fat more "stubborn" than other body fat?

Tags: stomach, body-weight

I am in the month of Ramadhan and my fast is almost 15 hrs each day. I can see overall changes: for example my shoulders and arms are getting lean but my stomach remains like a little bear belly. It is like nothing is happening there. Is there anything called a stubborn fat? Why do I see changes everywhere, but my belly still is big?

Comment: "bear belly" or "beer belly?"

Comment: Bear i guess. Like belly only hanging out @kate